# Python: Create a Main Menu page using flask

Tags: python, flask

I have the following code:

```
@app.route('/mainMenu', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainMenu():
    def name():
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        sqlFile = open('name.sql')
        sqlCode = sqlFile.read()
        cursor.execute(sqlCode, (session['name'],))
        user = cursor.fetchone()

        if request.method == 'GET':
            name = request.form["name"]
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            return render_template('mainMenu.html', user=user)
        return redirect(url_for('mainMenu'))
    def age():
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        sqlFile = open('age.sql')
        sqlCode = sqlFile.read()
        cursor.execute(sqlCode, (session['age']))
        user = cursor.fetchone()

        if request.method == 'GET':
            age = request.form["age"]
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            return render_template('mainMenu.html', user=user)
        return redirect(url_for('mainMenu'))
    def location():
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        sqlFile = open('location.sql')
        sqlCode = sqlFile.read()
        cursor.execute(sqlCode, (session['location']))
        user = cursor.fetchone()       
        if request.method == 'GET':
             location = request.form["location"]
             cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
             return render_template('mainMenu.html', user=user)
        return redirect(url_for('mainMenu'))
    def height():
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        sqlFile = open('height.sql')
        sqlCode = sqlFile.read()
        cursor.execute(sqlCode, (session['height']))
        user = cursor.fetchone()       
        if request.method == 'GET':
            height = request.form["height"]
            cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            return render_template('mainMenu.html', user=user)
        return redirect(url_for('mainMenu'))
     return redirect(url_for('mainMenu'))`
```

What I am trying to do is create a Main Menu page that displays Name, Age, Location, Height of each user when they login. The above code gives me this error:

`Too many redirects occurred to open "127.0.0.1:5000/mainMenu". This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which then is redirected to open the original page.`

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to have one page (main menu) that calls each function and returns the value for each (name, age, height and location) and then renders the template you want, so you should only have one render template or redirect at in there after the functions are called, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That solved the problem but now I am getting a a new error `Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.` I will investigate further into that. Do you have a guess as to why that's happening?

Comment: Is it perhaps that ‘mainMenu’ is not all lowercase?

Comment: It's not that. I'm still new to using flask so I can't really pinpoint where the issue is. Thanks for your help though :)